# CSS not apply until i refresh the page?

Tags: css, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have one strange issue with my personal [site](http://jitkasimkova.cz)

i wanted to customize footer logo (down left) and insered this CSS to move image a little under:

```
.page-id-769 .footer-row img {
margin-top:-30px;
}
.page-id-778  .footer-row img {
margin-top:-30px;
}
.page-id-98 .footer-row img {
margin-top:-30px;
}
.page-id-439 .footer-row img {
 margin-top:-30px;
}
.page-id-85 .footer-row img {
margin-top:-30px;
}
```

so to be i line with Copyright text (down right in footer), but loosk like when open the main site, on homepage is all ok, but if click on some page, my CSS not apply to that part due to some reason. If click F5 to refresh the page, my CSS is apply, and changes are visible. How to make CSS to works without need

to refrest the page, because looks theme is using Ajax for moving between pages in menu.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this, but I believe your website is only fully visible when you're logged in. To see what everyone else sees when going to your website, press Ctrl+Shift+N (in Chrome) and try to go to your website.

Comment: Sorry, now is visible. :)
Im talking about for this image: http://i.imgur.com/qObsHKA.png?1

Answer (score 1):

`.page-id-769` class is automatically appended only to the page with id `79`. If you want it to apply on all pages, use another class. present on all your pages. `.page` seems fit for the job:

```css
.page .footer-row img {
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Another option is to just use the footer id, which has more specificity:

```css
#footer .footer-row img { ... }
```

---

In regard to having to refresh the page to see `CSS` changes made to your `style.css`, this is because your browser keeps a copy of your `style.css` once you visited it and will use this copy when you revisit the page. There are several techniques to disable this behavior such as appending a random parameter to the file names when enqueue-ing them, or doing it on the fly using a `.htaccess` rule. Also, [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/busted) is available for this task.

However, keep in mind this should only be used when developing. It greatly impacts the site performance (because resources always reload, instead of being cached).

Another good option is to use a cache-ing plugin and just empty the cache whenever you want. It will do all the hard work for you (versioning resources).

Comment: Looks like this CSS dont change nothing.. Still without refresh the page, CSS is not showed in page. Try to open the page, after that click on Contact for example. Scroll to footer and see where is image. Press F5 to refresh the same page. Notice the difference.

Comment: What do you mean *"without refresh the page"*?

Comment: By default, your browser caches pages you visit, in order to display them faster. You need to disable cache or empty it if you want to hard reload it from server. That's normal. If you want to always force changes to go live without people needing to refresh, [read this](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/force-css-changes-to-go-live-immediately/).

Comment: Its not problem is that. The problem is that changes are not visible until you refresh the page. I think that CSS is not updating automatically, because when move between pages, page is not reloading, because theme is using Ajax for navigation between elements. To be more clear:
1. Open the site. click on Contact for example. Notice the position of image in footer.
2. Press F5, and notice that image wil be moved under from current position. That is problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. I have +8 years of WordPress experience, I'm author of two WP public plugins. Your theme uses VisualComposer, which saves custom styles in `/uploads/css/custom-styles.css`. You need to de-register that stylesheet and re-register it with a version number to force it to always refresh. I gave you an easier option, using a plugin while developing your website. But I'm not going to waste any more time trying to convince you. You want to believe it's ajax? Ok. It's ajax. :) Happy coding!

Comment: Its Ajax WP theme: https://themeforest.net/item/croma-responsive-music-wordpress-theme-with-ajax-and-continuous-playback/15182698

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution i found was run my java web project and when pages load without css style i press Crtl + F5, i think this key combination makes a hard refresh into your browser and load properly the .css file

Comment: I have the same problem on tomcat with PF. the problem is not loading the css but somehow browser style applied overrides page css. on refresh, the real css applied back. weird. this is happening on tomcat 7.0.85 ftw, on later releases of tomcat. issue is not available.